# PHP and MySQL not allowing Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on some code for a friend but my PHP code refuses to query the database even when I simplify it down to running without variables.

```
$sql = "SELECT message1, message2 FROM cards WHERE number = 5150671";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    Echo "Connection to the Database Success, Card Information Recieved.";
    $Message1 = $_row["message1"];
    $Message2 = $_row["message2"];
```

...etc

Full Code:
https://pastebin.com/jGs2xBFD

It returns a Query Failed error every time, the database, table, and rows are all named correctly and the values are in there.

cards @door_sign (localhost_3306) - Table
number  message1  message2
5150671        1         2

any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at your code again and very carefully. Go over it with a *fine toothed comb*.

Answer (score 0):

Missing something?

```
$result= $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 //stuff for the thing
}
```